# Adding foreign keys to rails database

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, migration, foreign-keys

I have a problem at the moment and am not sure what I should do. It is
in regards to relationships between tables and whether I need foreign
keys.

I have two tables in my database; users and games. Users includes all
the users information (username, email, address, password etc.) Games
includes all the games information (name, genre, console user_id). As
you may have noticed the games table includes the users id in order to
associate the relationship between the two which is every game needs an
associated user.

What I wish to do is on each games show.html.erb page, I have a button
which should send an email to the owner of that game in order to let
them now that the currently signed in user is interested in trading that
game.

I am wondering how I would do this. Does the user_id automatically link
all the users associated data or just the id. If not then how would I
declare the users email as a foreign key in order for me to call the
users email to be sent to?

Any help would be much appreciated. Thank you

Christopher Jones

UPDATE

Hey I had the following in my games_controller show section and it did not work. It threw the following error: undefined method `email' for "chris230391@googlemail.com":String.

```
def show
@game = Game.find(params[:id])

respond_to do |format|
  GameTrade.game_interest(@game.user.email).deliver
  format.html { redirect_to root_url }
  format.json { render json: @game }
end
end
```

So I changed it to the following in order to break down the problem and find out what line it broke on and it stated that the block was on line 19 which is the line g = GameTrade.game_interest(email). I got the following error:

undefined method `email' for "chris230391@googlemail.com":String

Any ideas? the code is below

```
def show
  @game = Game.find(params[:id])

respond_to do |format|
  user = @game.user
  email = user.email
  g = GameTrade.game_interest(email)
  g.deliver
  format.html { redirect_to root_url }
  format.json { render json: @game }
end
end
```

The following code is that of my Game_trade.rb in the mailer section:

```
  class GameTrade < ActionMailer::Base
    default :from => "christopher@aol.com"

    def game_interest(user)
      @user = user
      mail :to => user.email, :subject => "Game Interest"
    end
   end
```

Comment: Are you talking about real FKs in the database or the `:foreign_key` option to some Rails associations?

Comment: Hey I want to place a foreign key so that when I click the button it sends an email to the users email address. The email field does not exist in the games table, only the users and I have user_id in games but I don't think that gives access to the users email.

Comment: Hey I have updated my question above to give more insight on what I wish to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at [this Stack Overflow question regarding Rails and referential integrity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9458706/rails-and-referential-integrity). You may want to look into the [foreigner](https://github.com/matthuhiggins/foreigner) gem for adding and removing foreign keys during Rails migrations.

However, I'm curious as to why you're creating foreign key constraints beyond the game->user constraint you already have. Is there a reason you're denormalizing the username and email fields?

Comment: The reason I need to bring in the user email to each game is because I need a button in the game area that if you click it will send an email to the user who is associated with that email address. Does that make sense to you?

Comment: Hey I have updated my question above to give more insight on what I wish to do.

Comment: If you set up the relationship properly, then you can just call `game.user.email` — i.e., fetch the `User` record that's associated with the `Game`, and then fetch the `email` attribute of that `User`. If you place the user's e-mail address directly on the game, what happens when the user updates his e-mail? You now have to update every game associated with that user rather than a single `User` record.

Comment: That makes a lot of sense Brandan, I have updated my question above with further insight in to what I have done in the past few hours.

Comment: Your `game_interest` method is expecting a parameter of type `User`, but you're calling it with `@game.user.email`, which is a String.

Comment: Hey Brandan, how would I declare the users email as a object. Would I have to create a method in the user model in order to call the email field of a user and then call the model object in the above controller call?

Comment: I think your above code will work just fine if you replace `GameTrade.game_interest(email)` with `GameTrade.game_interest(user)`.

Comment: Brandan, that is wonderful, it fixed my problem :) Thank you for that all I need to do now is to put that call in a if statement instead as at the moment it is just sending the email upon clicking the show page rather than on button click. Thanks for that.

Answer (score 1):

The line `GameTrade.game_interest(@game.user.email).deliver`
calls the game_interest method in the GameTrade model.
(Please post that code also.)

This method expects a parameter and it's not getting it.

I would also consider making both the method and the call be for
`game_interest_deliver(@game.user.email).`

I worked in sql data warehousing for 5 years and I was very confused by rails and foreign keys initially.  The main lesson I've learned is not add them as appropriate but focus more on the ruby code and models and method to achieve the right results.

Comment: Hey Michael I have updated my post with the mailer class for Game_trade at the bottom.

Comment: The OP is using the correct conventions for `ActionMailer`. Your "notification" method returns a `Mail::Message` object (the result of the call to `mail`), and then you call `deliver` on that object to send the message. I also think it's correct to pass the `User` object to the method so that it's available to the view, which is responsible for constructing the e-mail message itself.

Comment: It seems all fine but I get this error message when I try to click on the show page for the game: undefined method `email' for "chris230391@googlemail.com":String. By the looks of it, it wont let me call it as it is a string rather than an object. How would I fix it?